# How can a Button be shifted to perform its action

Tags: gui-construction

I have a `Panel` with 4 `Inputfields` and a `Button`. When a `Button` is clicked, it shifts itself and adds two `Inputfields` in its place. Before clicking `Button`,

[image]

and after clicking `Button`.

[image]

I want to know how can I shift Button ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Dynamic` as in :

```
iField = Table[InputField[], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];

Panel[Dynamic@Grid[Join[iField, {{Button["Add", 
   AppendTo[iField, {InputField[], InputField[]}]], ""}}]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

A recursive solution would allow for the fields to stay intact when adding

```
DynamicModule[{var = False},
    Column[{Grid[{{InputField[], InputField[]}}],
      Dynamic[If[var, #0[], Button["Add", var = True]]
       ]}]
    ] &[] // Panel
```

However, you won't be able to go above approximately 50 I think